# Android OpenCV 3.1 load SVM classifier from file

Tags: android, opencv, classification, svm

In opencv 3.1 for Android, I don't find the load method for SVM class, but `save(String filename)` is available.

How can I load saved classifier from file? Any solutions will be accepted. I don't find any method to load classifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Some reason, Opencv is not implementing the method for loading trained models in the android sdks for any of the machine learning classes from opencv 3.0. In fact all machine learning classes inherits the `Algorithm` class in which Loading method should be there but it is not.

Possible solutions:
1.Downgrade opencv version to 2.4.10 or less in which the load method is present and it is working.
2.Implement your project in `c++` and make it run using **android NDK** if you are not interested in downgrading the opencv version.